# How to launch a PDF File using PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I want to get the time elapsed while opening a pdf file . I am not able to find a way to do it using PDFBox.I  created a PDDocument in my java program and want to use some API to launch the PDF file through my code .I am unable to find out which PDFBox  API that would serve the purpose.
So it would be helpful if i can get some info on that.

Thanks.
Swati

Answer (score 0):

Paste the file [04-Request-Headers.pdf](https://app.box.com/s/gyaysqdwuvkdeckkwdbm) in `Documents` folder in `C` drive.

If you execute the below java code it will opens the `04-Request-Headers.pdf` file in `Adobe Acrobat`. Total time to be taken to open the PDF file is displayed in console.

Below one is example of how to open the PDF file using Java.

**Code:**

```
package com.pdf.pdfbox.test;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;

public class OpenPDFFileUsingJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:/Documents/04-Request-Headers.pdf");
            if (file.exists()) {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("Total time taken to open file -> "+ file.getName() +" in "+ (endTime - startTime) +" ms");              
            } else {
                System.out.println("File not exits -> "+ file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:** `Total time taken to open file -> 04-Request-Headers.pdf in 94 ms`